# Android: Error upload image in different android versions

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am having problem with upload image in different android versions. I need to send images for php server, so i'm using a webservice. I did test with the versions Froyo e Jelly Beans, they works but the KitKat don't work. I was reading about MediaStore and I saw different ways and I don't if my its right or wrong.

I debbuged my project and I could see, in KitKat the path is NULL, Logcat tell me "Java Null Pointer" just in KitKat. How can i do a application works for all version.

UploadImage.java

```
package br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class EnviaFoto extends ActionBarActivity {

    final int PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;
    final int CAMERA_IMAGE =2;

    TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    Button btnTiraFoto;
    Button selectImage;
    ImageView imgFoto;

    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = "http://www.kweekdesign.com.br/test/recebe/UploadToServer.php";

    String filePath = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_envia_foto);

        selectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImage);
        imgFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        btnTiraFoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTiraFoto);

        upLoadServerUri = "http://www.kweekdesign.com.br/test/recebe/UploadToServer.php";

        addListeners();
    }

    public String uriToPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (data != null && (requestCode == PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE || requestCode == CAMERA_IMAGE)){

            filePath = uriToPath(data.getData());
            imgFoto.setImageURI(data.getData());
            uploadButton.setVisibility(1);

        }
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + filePath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+filePath);
                }
            });

            return 0;

        }
        else
        {
            try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "Envio feito com sucesso!";

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(EnviaFoto.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(EnviaFoto.this, "MalformedURLException",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(EnviaFoto.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }

    private void addListeners(){

        selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Escolha a foto");
                intent.setType("image/*");
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(chooser, PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE );
                }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(EnviaFoto.this, "", "Enviando foto...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public String uriToPath(Uri uri) {
                        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        return cursor.getString(column_index);
                    }


                    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
                        if (data != null && requestCode == PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE){

                            filePath = uriToPath(data.getData());
                            imgFoto.setImageURI(data.getData());
                            uploadButton.setVisibility(1);

                        }
                    } public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                messageText.setText("Enviando foto...");
                            }
                        });

                        uploadFile(filePath);

                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        btnTiraFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), CAMERA_IMAGE);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.envia_foto, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.Enquete"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enquete" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
07-04 08:46:54.084  13565-13565/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
    Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
07-04 08:46:54.157  13565-13565/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-04 08:47:03.105  13565-13565/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-04 08:47:03.121  13565-13565/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao, PID: 13565
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3432)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1420)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:445)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
            at br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto.uriToPath(EnviaFoto.java:80)
            at br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto.onActivityResult(EnviaFoto.java:97)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5446)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3428)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-04 08:47:05.066  13565-13565/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 13565 SIG: 9
07-04 08:51:33.298  15518-15518/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
    Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
07-04 08:51:33.393  15518-15518/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-04 08:52:08.015  15518-15530/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao W/CursorWrapperInner﹕ Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-04 08:52:10.068  15518-16522/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-34287
    Process: br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao, PID: 15518
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
            at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
            at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
            at br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto.uploadFile(EnviaFoto.java:102)
            at br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto$6$1.run(EnviaFoto.java:277)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
07-04 08:52:10.815  15518-15518/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{65280820 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:359)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
            at br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto$6.onClick(EnviaFoto.java:250)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-04 09:03:23.546  18083-18083/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
    Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
07-04 09:03:23.614  18083-18083/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-04 09:04:14.226  18083-18096/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao W/CursorWrapperInner﹕ Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-04 09:04:14.428  18083-18083/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
    Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
07-04 09:04:17.318  18083-19131/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-34498
    Process: br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao, PID: 18083
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
            at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
            at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
            at br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto.uploadFile(EnviaFoto.java:100)
            at br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto$6$1.run(EnviaFoto.java:275)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
07-04 09:04:18.179  18083-18083/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{65280100 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:359)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
            at br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto$6.onClick(EnviaFoto.java:248)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Updated after Instance Dialog

```
07-04 09:54:17.341 26763-26763/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 07-04 09:54:17.364 26763-26763/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao, PID: 26763 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao/br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto}: java.lang.InstantiationException: br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: br.gov.rj.barraemexposicao.EnviaFoto at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1561) at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Comment: ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog();

Comment: Error:(41, 29) error: no suitable constructor found for ProgressDialog(no arguments) constructor ProgressDialog.ProgressDialog(Context) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor ProgressDialog.ProgressDialog(Context,int) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: you have to put constructer there.. `dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: Like this? ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());

Comment: yes its should be like this if you are using Activity class....or if you are using it in fragment is should be `getActivity()`

Comment: Ok, but i was running and my project stop the work..

Comment: I cann't post log here, i was updated in the question

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Okay, regarding this exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
```

**You might get this exception while using *Photos* app, but not quite often in *Gallery* app. This might be important to know because in Android's latest version 5.0 *Lollipop*, they have removed *Gallery* app now they have *Photos* app only (Different vendors may have their own other in-built apps for photos & of course user can use any external apps also)**

And because of this you are getting `filePath = null'. Now the question is *why is it null?*.

So there may be two reasons..

1st is your `uriToPath(Uri uri)` method is not working correctly & 2nd is your `Uri` which you are getting from `data.getData()` is not correct.

Your `uriToPath(Uri uri)` method seems to be correct, so the problem is in your `Uri`.
You might have noticed that if you are fetching images from *Gallery* app, there are less chances that you are getting `null` in `filePath`, but if you are using *Photos* app the chances increase.

It happens because your *Photos* app shows photos which may not be on your local device, these photos are actually on the Google server. So when you ask for `Uri` by selecting a photo, it gives the *Uri* which is linked to that server.

The Uri might be like this *`content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https%3A%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2FL-3Jm0TaSqnuKkitli5mK0-d`*

& its not of your local device.
Local device's `Uri` will be like this

*`content://media/external/images/media/49518`*

Because of this difference your `uriToPath(Uri uri)` is returning `null`.

So check the `Uri` first & accordingly fetch image from local device or server.

You can use [DocumentsProvider API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) so you won't have to worry about the local & server's files.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
             getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
}
```

But if you have some local photos in *Photos* app then on selecting those you will get the local *Uri*, which will give you the correct file path.

You can also download the photos (which are on Google server) in *Photos* app itself & later use it.

Comment: What if - I am getting uri from ---   Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(1))?

Comment: If you have the local file you will get a local uri, so in that case you should use normal way or as I mentioned just use DocumentsProvider API e.g. method in my answer.

Comment: @AB1209, I agree with above comment but its contradicts with the statement in Post "You can use DocumentsProvider API so you won't have to worry about the local & server's files.". Which made me to think that I could use getBitmapFromUri method for local and server files. But its not worked. I just wish you should edit that statement in your answer post with the above Comment. Just fyi only. Please never mind if i'm wrong. Your answer really helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code, for api > 19 the retrieving image differs

```
       txtlogochange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent();
                   intent.setType("image/*");
                   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
               }
           });

   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    // System.out.println("selectedImage "+selectedImage);
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    smallImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    System.out.println("smallImagePath" + smallImagePath);
                    logoImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(smallImagePath));
                    encodeImage();
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        InputStream imInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imInputStream);
                        smallImagePath = saveGalaryImageOnLitkat(bitmap);
                        logoImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(smallImagePath));
                        encodeImage();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // finishAndSetResult(RESULT_OK, picturePath, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private File temp_path;
    private final int COMPRESS = 100;
    private String saveGalaryImageOnLitkat(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            File cacheDir;
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                cacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            else
                cacheDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            if (!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();
            String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(cacheDir, filename);
            temp_path = file.getAbsoluteFile();
            // if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESS, out);
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: WOKING GOOD THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Use this below method in onActivityResult it surley work on every device.

```
Uri selectedImageUri  =null;
try {
                            Path = data.getExtras().getString("dataImg");

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        try {
                            if (Path == null) {

                                Path = data.getData().toString();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            if (Path == null) {
                                Path = data.getExtras().getString("data");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            if (Path == null) {
                                Uri newPhotoUri = null;
                                newPhotoUri = data.getData();
                                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                                CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this,
                                        newPhotoUri, projection, null, null,
                                        null);
                                Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();

                                int column_index_data = cursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                                cursor.moveToFirst();
                                Path = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {

                            if (Path == null) {
                                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                                if (selectedImageUri == null) {
                                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras()
                                            .get("data");
                                    selectedImageUri = getImageUri(
                                            Survey_Elabel.this, photo);
                                }

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Method used for getting URI.

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When moving from activity to camera app, onSaveInstanceState is not called, we have to save our image path / Uri to onPause() method by sharedPreference.
On restoreInstanceState method we have to retrieved our image path from shared preference.